# Performance drop after 5 days running web application, how to spot the bottleneck?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, scala, playframework

I've developed a web application using the following tech stack:

- Java
- Mysql
- Scala
- Play Framework
- DavMail integration (for calender and exchange server)
- Javamail
- Akka actors

On the first days, the application runs smoothly and without lags. But after 5 days or so, the application gets really slow! And now I have no clue how to profile this, since I have huge dependencies and it's hard to reproduce this kind of thing. I have looked into the memory and it seems that everything its okay.

Any pointers on the matter?

Comment: You can also check the versions of everything you're running on their official pages. Maybe the problem's not from your code ( however, this is unlikely ) and something has been already fixed?

Answer (score 10):

Try using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) - you can monitor gc behaviour, memory usage, heap, threads, cpu usage etc. You can use it to connect to a remote VM.

Answer (score 7):

`visualvm˙ is also a great tool for such purposes, you can connect to a remote JVM as well and see what's inside.

I suggest you doing this:

- take a snapshot of the application running since few hours and since 5 days
- compare thread counts
- compare object counts, search for increasing numbers
- see if your program spends more time in particular methods on the 5th day than on the 1str one
- check for disk space, maybe you are running out of it

Answer (score 6):

`jconsole` comes with the JDK and is an easy tool to spot bottlenecks. Connect it to your server, look into memory usage, GC times, take a look at how many threads are alive because it could be that the server creates many threads and they never exit.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with tulskiy. On top of that you could also use `JMeter` if the investigations you will have made with `jconsole` are unconclusive.

The probable causes of the performances degradation are threads (that are created but never exit) and also memory leaks: if you allocate more and more memory, before having the `OutOfMemoryError`, you may encounter some performances degradation (happened to me a few weeks ago).

Answer (score 3):

To eliminate your database you can monitor slow queries (and/or queries that are not using an index) using the slow query log
see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

I would hazard a guess that you have a missing index, and it has only become apparent as your data volumes have increased.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another profiler is [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/).
It is commercial, but with trial period (two weeks).
Actually, I've firstly tried `VisualVM` as @axel22 suggested, but our remote server was ssh'ed and we had problems with connecting via VisualVM (not saying that it is impossible, I've just surrendered after a few hours).

Answer (score 2):

You might just want to try the **'play status'** command, which will list web app state (threads, jobs, etc). This might give you a hint on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

So guys, in this specific case, I was running play in Developer mode, which makes the compiler works every now and then.

After changing to production mode, everything was lightning fast and no more problems anymore. But thanks for all the help.