# How to use VisualVM to spot the bottleneck/problem

Tags: java, scala, profiler, visualvm

As I posted in [Performance drop after 5 days running web application, how to spot the bottleneck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146662/performance-drop-after-5-days-running-web-application-how-to-spot-the-bottleneck) , I have a problem with an application that gets slow after running for a while.

I got VisualVM running and made a snapshot between different times. Now the application is really slow, but I have no idea how to spot the bottleneck. They don't have many differences between each other and the only thing that grows a bit is the Heap, which is successfully garbage collected after a while.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Here are the snapshots (apps):

[1] http://www.2shared.com/file/W4XJ6HtE/application-1314108550032.html

[2] http://www.2shared.com/fadmin/22521338/f512f97e/application-1314097232727.apps.html

Thank you!

EDIT: Looking closer, I've noticed that the CPU is not even being used much.. and the system is really slow!

Comment: In the second snapshot (which goes over an hour while the first goes over 4 seconds only) there is some load on the CPU and nearly no load created by the GC. If the CPU is the bottleneck you should try to profile which methods are causing this. You can do this within jvisualvm, too.

Comment: What app server is the application running on?  Is it behind a web server front-end?  If yes, how are the 2 connected (which module).

Answer (score 6):

As a first step I would suggest to identify what exactly is slow. Does it execute some job slowly? Or demonstrates low throughput on handling jobs from different clients?

What resource is unsufficient?

- If you are using some external services (like database or RPC server) *always* log their response time and check it before making any other optimization steps.
- It could be a lack of processor power. Just look at CPU usage.
- It could be a lack of memory. Use gc logging to detect such kind of issues. There is a [good topic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/example-141412.html) about it.
- It could be a lack of hard drive speed. Use the iostat and know your HDD performance limits.
- It could be a lack of network throughput. Check network channel usage.
- Also it is possible that you run out of some OS-specific limits, like number of opened files and/or network sockets. Check that you properly report all OS-level exception into log files.

As you have identified which resource is unsufficient and the part of your program which suffers from it you could try to find the piece of code to optimize. Taking a random tool and run your application through it without knowing what to look for makes no sense.

From my personal experience it is very rare case when you have just a slow method, which could be found with a profiler. Most likely it is an unexpected IO and/or synchronisation somewhere in your algorithm or bad database schema.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there are some better tools than VisualVM.

You could try JProfiler, which is a nice profiler (but paid)

And you could try the Netbeans profiler, which is free and works great

With VisualVM you'll only see the actual state of your application (memory and cpu usage, JMXs, classes loaded, etc).

Comment: There are better tools; but this does not mean that you need them in this case (what I currently can't judge). JvisualVM also includes a profiler (both instrumenting and sampling) and a memory profiler. Also you can install additional plugins.

Comment: @ziggystar Good to know, didn't knew that!

Comment: @KicoLobo, does `VisualVM` shows the sql queries being fired by the application?

Comment: NetBeans profiler seems VisualVM embedded in NB IDE. They even say to download VisualVM if you just want a standalone profiler (https://profiler.netbeans.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I would not assume right off the bat its an issue with your application, If its a windows based system look at virus scanner, any update scheduler running at that time.

Make sure your logs are rolling over and debugging is filtered properly so they are not growing out of control.

Check the sql snapshots for any long running queries. Check DB load and DB heap.

If you have Visual VM running for a while make sure you have some threads ready to accept work/connections will show as yellow (idle).

A shot in the dark
[Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Take a heap dump when you notice a slowdown and run it through the analyzer.

If your on a unix based system check file descriptors  ulimit -a  to make sure the java process has not max'd out.

Check the TCP NO Delay and Nagle limit settings on the server